# Linear functionals on the space of measurable functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Let us consider the following space of all measurable functions on $[0,1]$ with the metric: $$d(f, g) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{|f-g|}{1 + |f-g|}d\mu.$$ It is the metric of convergence in measure on $[0,1]$ ($\mu$ - standard Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$). I have problems with the proof that every continuous functional on this space is zero. I.e. there are no nontrivial continuous linear functionals on this (metric) space.

Comment: Show that the convex hull of every ball is the entire space.

Comment: Seems like great idea, thank you!

Comment: No. It is still not clear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the following

> **Proposition:** Let $E$ be a topological vector space (not necessarily Hausdorff) over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. There exists a nonzero continuous linear functional on $E$ if and only if there is a convex neighbourhood of $0$ that isn't the whole space.

**Proof:** Let $\lambda \neq 0$ be a continuous linear functional on $E$. Then $U = \lambda^{-1}(\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\})$ is a convex and balanced proper subset of $E$. Since $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$ is open (in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, as the case may be), and $\lambda$ is continuous, it follows that $U$ is open, and since $0\in U$, we see that $0$ has a nontrivial [meaning not the entire space] convex neighbourhood of $0$.

Conversely, suppose $V\neq E$ is a convex neighbourhood of $0$ in $E$. The Minowski functional

$$\mu_V \colon x \mapsto \inf \{ t > 0 : x \in tV\}$$

is then a sublinear functional (since $V$ is convex). Choose $x_0 \in E\setminus V$. By the Hahn-Banach extension lemma, we can find a real-linear functional $\lambda \colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\lambda(x_0) = \mu_V(x_0)$ and $\lambda(x) \leqslant \mu_V(x)$ for all $x\in E$. Then $V \subset \lambda^{-1}\bigl((-1,1)\bigr)$, which shows that $\lambda$ is continuous. If $E$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, we're done, and if it's a complex vector space, let $\tilde{\lambda}(x) = \lambda(x) - i\lambda(ix)$ be the complex linear functional with real part $\lambda$. Clearly $\tilde{\lambda}$ is also continuous, and $\tilde{\lambda} \neq 0$.

---

Hence, to show that on a topological vector space no nonzero continuous linear functional exists, it suffices to show that the only convex neighbourhood of $0$ is the whole space. Equivalently, the convex hull of every neighbourhood of $0$ is the whole space.

Now, in the space $\mathscr{M}([0,1])$ of measurable functions on $[0,1]$, endowed with the pseudometric

$$d(f,g) = \int_0^1 \frac{\lvert f(x) - g(x)\rvert}{1 + \lvert f(x) - g(x)\rvert}\,dx$$

(we get a proper metric if we divide out the space of functions vanishing almost everywhere, but that's not necessary to do), let $V$ a neighbourhood of $0$. By definition of the topology, there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that

$$B_{\varepsilon}(0) = \{ f \in \mathscr{M}([0,1]) : d(f,0) < \varepsilon\} \subset V.$$

Choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$. For $g \in \mathscr{M}([0,1])$ and $0 \leqslant k < n$, let

$$g_k(x) = \begin{cases} n\cdot g(x) &, \frac{k}{n} \leqslant x < \frac{k+1}{n} \\ \quad 0 &, \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

(for $k = n-1$, let $g_{n-1}(x) = n\cdot g(x)$ on the closed interval $\bigl[\frac{n-1}{n},1\bigr]$ rather than on the half-open interval). Then we have

$$d(g_k,0) = \int_0^1 \frac{\lvert g_k(x)\rvert}{1 + \lvert g_k(x)\rvert}\,dx = \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} \frac{n\lvert g(x)\rvert}{1 + n\lvert g(x)\rvert}\,dx < \int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} 1\,dx = \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon,$$

and hence

$$g = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}\cdot g_k$$

belongs to the convex hull of $B_{\varepsilon}(0)$.

Thus $\operatorname{conv} V = \mathscr{M}([0,1])$ for every neighbourhood of $0$, which by the proposition above implies that there is no nonzero continuous linear functional on $\mathscr{M}([0,1])$.

Answer (score 0):

This is Problem 51(vi) of Chapter 14 in *Real Analysis,* fourth edition, by Royden and Fitzpatrick. Minkowski functionals are not introduced at that point in the text. Rather, the authors give the following hint:

> Let $\psi: X\to\mathbf R$ be linear and continuous where $X$ is your space. Show that there is a real number $b$ such that $\psi(c) = 0$ whenever $c$ is the characteristic function of an interval of length less than $1/b$. Hence, $\psi(h) = 0$ for all step functions $h$.

Let $c$ be the characteristic function of an interval $(a,a + 1/b]$ contained in $[0,1]$. If $a = 0$, read $(a,a + 1/b]$ as $[0,1/b]$. Because $\psi$ is continuous, there is a $\delta$ for which if $\rho(\lambda c,0) <\delta$, then $|\psi(\lambda c) - 0| < 1$ where $\lambda$ is an nonzero real number. Now
$$\rho(\lambda c,0) =\int_0^1\frac{|\lambda c - 0|}{1 +|\lambda c - 0|} =\int_a^{a+1/b}\frac{|\lambda c|}{1 +|\lambda c|} <\int_a^{a+1/b} 1 =\frac1b.$$
Choose $b$ large enough so that $\rho(\lambda c,0) <\delta$. In that case, $|\psi(\lambda c)| < 1$, or $|\psi(c)| < 1/|\lambda|$ by linearity of $\psi$. Because that holds for $|\lambda|$ arbitrarily large, $\psi(c) = 0$. Thus, there is a $b$ such that $\psi(c) = 0$ whenever $c$ is the characteristic function of an interval of length less than $1/b$.

Step functions are linear combinations of such characteristic functions; hence, $\psi(h) = 0$ for all step functions $h$ by linearity of $\psi$.

We next show that the set of step functions on $[0,1]$ is dense in $X$. Take a nonempty open subset of $X$. Because the subset is nonempty, it contains a function $f$ of $X$. And because the subset is open, it contains an open ball centered at $f$ of radius $\epsilon$. If necessary, reduce $\epsilon$ so that $0 <\epsilon < 3$. By Lusin's theorem, there is a continuous function $g$ on $\mathbf R$ and a closed set $F$ contained in $[0,1]$ for which
$$f = g\text{ on $F$ and }m([0,1]\sim F) <\epsilon/3.$$
Set $F$ is nonempty because $\epsilon < 3$ and bounded because $F\subseteq [0,1]$. Then $g$ is bounded on $F$ by the extreme value theorem. Moreover, $g$ is measurable on $F$ because it equals measurable function $f$ on $F$ (or because $g$ is continuous on $F$). By Problem 18 of Chapter 3, there is a step function $h$ on $F$ and a measurable subset $A$ of $F$ for which
$$|h - f| <\epsilon/3\text{ on $A$ and }m(F\sim A) <\epsilon/3.$$
Then\begin{align}
\rho(f,h) & =\int_0^1\frac{|f - h|}{1 +|f - h|}\\
& <\int_{[0,1]\sim F} 1 +\int_{F\sim A} 1 +\int_A\frac\epsilon3\\
& <\epsilon/3 +\epsilon/3 +\epsilon/3\\
& =\epsilon,\end{align}
which shows that $h$ is contained in the open ball and therefore in the open subset. Hence, the set of step functions on $[0,1]$ is dense in $X$.

We have shown that $\psi$ takes the same values as the zero functional on a dense subset of metric space $X$. Hence, $\psi = 0$ on $X$. Thus, there are no nonzero continuous linear functionals on $X$.